# How can I create and access instance variables in odoo models

Tags: python, odoo

My code is:

```
class way_bill(osv.osv):
    _name = "way_bill"
    ....
    def method1(...):
       self.ID = self.get_id_invoice_id(...)

    def method2(...):
        for item self.browse(cr, uid, self.ID, context=context):
        ....
```

When I try to access `self.ID` form `method2`, it raises an error.

How can I store and use `self.ID`?

Comment: Did you mean to indent the "methods" to make them part of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: which version are you using for coding? .v7 or .v8?

If `ID` is an Integer, in .v8 you can use a decorator `@depends` shomething like this:

```
@api.depends('ID')
def method2(self):
    for item self.browse(self.ID):
    ...
```

I hope this can be helpful for you.

**EDIT**

In .v7 it should be something like this:

```
def method1(...):
    return { 'values': { 'ID': self.get_id_invoice_id(...)}}

def method2(...):        
    record = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)        
    obj_inv = self.browse(cr, uid, record.ID, context=context)        
    ...
```

I don't know what ID are you locking for, even how you do that in `get_id_invoice_id`, but if you apply the changes, it should br work perfectly...

Comment: I use openerp (.v7).

Comment: In .v7 you don't asigned 'self.my_fiell=value', that syntax is only for .v8, let me edit my answer to show you how to do that.